# Could not find method artifactory() [Gradle 7.+]

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory, android-gradle-7.0

I am using Gradle 7.+ and we know its structure is different.

Now how can setup `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin on gradle 7.+?

My JFrog artifactory using legacy gradle installation !

[image]

[image]

I tried to setup using gradle DSL & legacy one, But I got the same issue `Could not find method artifactory()`

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, the issue appears to be with the class invocation. Adding the `apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"`[OR] turning the 'apply' tag to `true` in the "`com.jfrog.artifactory`" section should help.